# Ubuntu 17.04 - Gedit [Text Document]

Tags: gedit, text

Have upgraded from **Ubuntu 16.04 - 17.04** and i noticed a lot of changes.
Some good, some not so good.

**1.** Right click on empty space

**2.** Select: New Document

**3.** *STOP*

There is no Text Document option to open, instead i see a list of something that i have installed.

Where it is supposed to say: (Empty Document) I see the folders that i have saved in **Templates**. But no where to click to actually open an empty document.

However, if i open an already existing text document and right click on it in the menu bar **then** i can choose **New Document** and choose where to save it. But not directly in a folder or on the desktop.

**P.S** I for some unknown reason can not take screenshots of it.

Comment: You should at least have the "new empty document" option there. Did you click in a directory where you have write permission?

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would be helpful?

Comment: kevlarjacket: I would if i could. As soon as i right click the mouse i can't take screenshots. However i made a smal update in the main post.

Comment: Jos: If i do not have permission something is really wrong in this version since i'm the head admin of pc.

Comment: Don't you have a `+` icon for tab? That's for empty new document!

Comment: What's your question? In the current state your post is a bug report or feature request and no question which are off topic on Ask Ubuntu and should be reported on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/).

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 16.10 and Later:**

Later versions of Nautilus ("Files") removed this feature so you cannot create a blank text-file by just clicking anywhere. You need to use the "Templates" folder for this purpose.

To do this, first navigate to your templates directory: Templates folder

Then open a Terminal in that folder (by right clicking > "Open in Terminal") and then type the following command in the terminal.

```
touch "Blank Document"
```

You can name this file anything you want. I personally prefer "Blank Document" because what it creates is essentially a blank document.

After this you should be able to create blank text-files anywhere you want (and are allowed to): creating a blank-document Ubuntu 17.04

Note: You can use the Templates folder to do many other things like creating a particular image, etc. Anything you put there will appear in the "New Document" menu.

*[Is there any way to create a simple txt file without opening the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917502/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-simple-txt-file-without-opening-the-terminal)*

Comment: HI Matas and thank you for your answer. This issue only accured in Ubuntu 17.04, I have never had this issue before with any earlier versions of Ubuntu. I simply just want to open a normal blank and empty (Text Document) to able to write in and save plain text. That i can do now since I changed back to Ubuntu 16.04. So no matter if i right click on the Desktop or in a Folder i will get this option: New Document » Empty Docuemnt.