# How to make text file in 17.04

Tags: gui, 17.04, text-editor

So how I can make it via GUI? Right-click just shows 'Create folder'
I dont see that option

Comment: Its not, i dont  see document

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of the menu you get?

Comment: Actually I just see that since 16.10, that option got removed from the context menu. See this answer to the question linked as duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/917723/367990

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/KUYpP